# Why would a working SQL query not work as a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, subquery

I have the following query, which works and produces the output I need it to.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(SELECT
  ref_year, ref_no, min(sequence_number) sequence_number
FROM
  case_decisions
WHERE
  stage = 'C'
AND
  decision_code <> 'IA'
GROUP BY
  ref_year,
  ref_no
) temp

INNER JOIN /* Produce table of first decisions only */
  case_decisions cdec
ON
  temp.ref_year = cdec.ref_year
AND
  temp.ref_no = cdec.ref_no
AND
  temp.sequence_number = cdec.sequence_number;
```

If, however, I try to use it as a subquery join (as follows) to another working query I get an error saying fdec.ref_no is not a valid identifier. I presume there is a problem with the way I've written the subquery but can't find it.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    ref_year, ref_no, min(sequence_number) sequence_number
  FROM
    case_decisions
  WHERE
    stage = 'C'
  AND
    decision_code <> 'IA'
  GROUP BY
    ref_year,
    ref_no
  ) temp

INNER JOIN /* Produce table of first decisions only */
  case_decisions cdec
ON
  temp.ref_year = cdec.ref_year
AND
  temp.ref_no = cdec.ref_no
AND
  temp.sequence_number = cdec.sequence_number
) fdec
ON
  resolved.ref_year = fdec.ref_year
AND
  resolved.ref_no = fdec.ref_no
```

Giving a full query of:

```
SELECT
  resolved.*,
  fdec.decision_code initial_decision

FROM
  (SELECT
    t1.ref_year,
    t1.ref_no,
    t1.date_decision_status_achieved,
    t1.sequence_number
  FROM
    case_decisions t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    case_decisions t2
  ON
    (t1.ref_year = t2.ref_year
  AND
    t1.ref_no = t2.ref_no
  AND
    t1.sequence_number < t2.sequence_number)
WHERE
  t2.ref_year IS NULL
AND
  t2.ref_no IS NULL
AND
  (t1.status = 8 OR t1.status =11)
AND
  t1.decision_code <> 'IA'
AND
  t1.date_decision_status_achieved between '01-APR-2008' and '01-JUN-2008' /* dates for testing purposes only */) resolved

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT
  *
FROM
  (SELECT
    ref_year, ref_no, min(sequence_number) sequence_number
  FROM
    case_decisions
  WHERE
    stage = 'C'
  AND
    decision_code <> 'IA'
  GROUP BY
    ref_year,
    ref_no
  ) temp

INNER JOIN /* Produce table of first decisions only */
  case_decisions cdec
ON
  temp.ref_year = cdec.ref_year
AND
  temp.ref_no = cdec.ref_no
AND
  temp.sequence_number = cdec.sequence_number) fdec
ON
  resolved.ref_year = fdec.ref_year
AND
  resolved.ref_no = fdec.ref_no
;
```

I've had a look at similar SO questions but none seem to be trying what I am (I expect an indication I'm doing something wrong). Any suggestions for what I'm missing here?

Comment: Please post the full query giving problems.

Comment: Got a downvote on this, could someone tell me why so I can avoid repeating the mistake? Thanks.

Comment: In that final query you have "SELECT resolved.*, fdec.decision_code initial_decision". What is initial_decision supposed to be? I'm assuming it is not a column name since I don't see it anywhere else and there is no comma before it. Never used oracle and I have never seen that before so curious as to what it means/is used for.

Comment: @Bryan it's just an alias for the column fdec.decision_code. These are used to make the final output more readable for the intended audience.

Comment: Ah thanks, I should have realized that. With the sqls I use I usually see an "as" between the column name and the alias but I guess that isn't always required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
select * 
from (
    select ref_year,
        ref_no,
        min(sequence_number) sequence_number
    from case_decisions
    where stage = 'C'
        and decision_code <> 'IA'
    group by ref_year,
        ref_no
    ) temp
inner join case_decisions cdec on temp.ref_year = cdec.ref_year
    and temp.ref_no = cdec.ref_no
    and temp.sequence_number = cdec.sequence_number
) fdec on resolved.ref_year = fdec.ref_year
```

You are selecting `ref_no` twice (once from `temp` and once from `cdec` because of the `*`), so it does not know which `ref_no` column to refer to. Instead of `*`, reference only the columns you need.

Try this version:

```
select resolved.*,
    fdec.decision_code initial_decision
from (
    select t1.ref_year,
        t1.ref_no,
        t1.date_decision_status_achieved,
        t1.sequence_number
    from case_decisions t1
    left outer join case_decisions t2 on (
            t1.ref_year = t2.ref_year
            and t1.ref_no = t2.ref_no
            and t1.sequence_number < t2.sequence_number
        )
    where t2.ref_year is null
        and t2.ref_no is null
        and (
            t1.status = 8
            or t1.status = 11
        )
        and t1.decision_code <> 'IA'
        and t1.date_decision_status_achieved between '01-APR-2008' and '01-JUN-2008' /* dates for testing purposes only */
) resolved
left outer join (
    select temp.ref_year, temp.ref_no, cdec.decision_code
    from (
        select ref_year,
            ref_no,
            min(sequence_number) sequence_number
        from case_decisions
        where stage = 'C'
            and decision_code <> 'IA'
        group by ref_year,
            ref_no
    ) temp
    inner join case_decisions cdec on temp.ref_year = cdec.ref_year
        and temp.ref_no = cdec.ref_no
        and temp.sequence_number = cdec.sequence_number
) fdec on resolved.ref_year = fdec.ref_year
    and resolved.ref_no = fdec.ref_no;
```

Comment: Full query added now, thanks. SQL developer suggests all brackets are matched.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the "*" brings in two columns named "ref_no" into the subquery, because temp and cdec both have the column.

Try changing the select to:

```
select cdec.*, temp.sequence_number
```

I've seen this error before in other databases, but the message is much clearer.